# how to access defined class fields in a list in android?

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class ClsConfig {

    private int SrlConfig;
    private String ValConfig;
    private String Desc;

    public void SetSrlConfig(int srl){
            this.SrlConfig=srl;
        }

    public int GetSrlConfig(){
            return SrlConfig;
        }

    public void SetValConfig(String val){
            this.ValConfig=val;
        }

    public String GetValConfig(){
            return ValConfig;
        }

    public void SetDescConfig(String desc){
        this.Desc=desc;
    }

    public String GetDescConfig(){
        return Desc;
    }
}
```

I use this method to read data from the database and make a list of my class objects:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")

public List getAllConfig() {
    List lstConfig = new ArrayList();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBActs.tableName,
    configColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        ClsConfig config = parseConfig(cursor);
        lstConfig.add(config);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return lstConfig;
}


private ClsConfig parseConfig(Cursor cursor) {
    ClsConfig config= new ClsConfig();
    config.SetSrlConfig(cursor.getInt(0));
    config.SetValConfig(cursor.getString(1));
    config.SetDescConfig(cursor.getString(2));
    return config ;
}
```

Imagine that these methods work fine with no error. Right now the method named `getAllConfig()` returns a list of objects of class `ClsConfig`. My question is, how can I read the `ValConfig` field of the first index returned data by method `getAllConfig()`? (Imagine that I want to show `ValConfig` content in an `EditText`).

Comment: `ClsConfig config = (ClsConfig) getAllConfig().get(0);  config.GetValConfig();`

Answer (score 0):

```
ClsConfig config = (ClsConfig) getAllConfig().get(0);

config.GetValConfig();
```